# c# extract data from pdf file

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I was trying to extract the data from pdf file using `iTextSharp`, but i go two errors. Actually I want to extract the data from pdf file and store it into database.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.util.collections;
using System.Linq;

public partial class frm_CreatePDF : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string P_InputStream3 = "~/My Documents/List Of Holidays 2012";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExtractText();
    }

    private string ExtractText()
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath(P_InputStream3));
        string txt = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 2, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
        return txt;
    }
}
```

And the error is:

> 1. The name 'PdfTextExtractor' does not exist in the current context
> 2. The type or namespace name 'LocationTextExtractionStrategy

Comment: Did you add reference to the dll?

Comment: First of all you need to add a reference to the ItextSharp dll, after wich you can add a using statement to acces the namespace that contains that static class.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have brought the namespace in which those two classes are defined into scope by adding the `using` directive:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
```

Comment: "The type or namespace name 'parser' does not exist in the namespace 'iTextSharp.text.pdf' (are you missing an assembly reference?)",, this is what the error i got

Comment: can you find what error is this.. or else you want me to give the explanation for this error.....

Comment: I guess you are using some old version of iTextSharp. Download the latest one.

Comment: I tried using iTextSharp, and what it gave me was, not the contents of the PDF, but this text instead (NOTE: I *can* open the PDF directly on my PC and view it, so this msg is bogus):
Please Wait...
If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF
viewer may not be able to display this type of document.
You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows®, Mac, or LinuX® by
visiting http://WWW.adobe.conﬂproducts/acrobat/readstep2.html.
For more assistance with Adobe Reader visit http://www.adobe.conﬂsupport/products/
acrreader.html....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use another namespace where LocationTextExtractionStrategy is defined

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add a reference to the ItextSharp dll, after wich you can add a using statement to acces the namespace that contains that static class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: i know how to add the reference. would you tell what reference i have missed. can you???

Comment: check the iTextSharp documentation examples first, no one can read telepathically what your exact problem is.

Comment: i have already given my code and error too. so nobody wants to read the problem through telepathy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but I've found what your issue is:

You are missing the `iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser` using statement. Add this below your `using iTextSharp.text.pdf;` code:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
```

That should be able to find your `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` pretty well.

You can also just add `iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser` directly behind your `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` if you want.

```
string txt =  PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 2, new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
```

But I would recommend the former. It's cleaner and easier to read.